# Simulink - programmatically specifying external inputs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to adjust some Simulink parameters programmatically, namely specifying external inputs and initial state. The Mathworks' help document on [Data Import/Export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/gui/bq7cpr_.html#bq8qrx_-1_1) shows how to do so both visually and programmatically. Apparently for external inputs, I need to specify `LoadExternalInputs` to `'on'`; I would like to override the default external input via `ExternalInput` to `[myTimeVar, myInputVar]`, as documented in that link.

Trying to run the command

```
sim('mySim', 'LoadExternalInputs', 'on', 'ExternalInput', [myTimeVar, myInputVar]);
```

yields the following error message:

> Invalid setting in block_diagram 'mySim' for parameter 'ExternalInput'

If I'm not supposed to specify my external input in the `sim()` call, where am I supposed to do it? I'm quite confused as to how to specify my inputs and states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ExternalInput parameter must be a string, try this:

```
sim('mySim', 'LoadExternalInputs', 'on', 'ExternalInput', '[myTimeVar, myInputVar]');
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The documentation is inconsistent, it looks like, as it says `ExternalInput` defaults to `[t,u]` rather than `'[t,u]'`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @MikeT, the `sim` command works in a parameter name-value fashion, so both the parameter name and value must be strings. The command should be:

```
sim('mySim','LoadExternalInput', 'on', 'ExternalInput', [myTimeVar, myInputVar]);
```

I believe the parameter `'LoadExternalInput'` is not necessary, but in any case, it is `'LoadExternalInput'` rather than `'LoadExternalInputs'`. I checked it with `get_param('modelName','ObjectParameters')`

Some important remarks:

Remark #1:

When using `sim`, Simulink automatically switches the workspace to the model's, so one might get errors if `sim` is executed within a MATLAB function or unitTest.

Remark #2

In the pair `'ExternalInput','Inputs'`, `'Inputs'` should contain the column-wise concatenation of all the column vectors inputs, starting with the time vector: `'[myTimeVar, myInputVar1, myInputVar2, ..., myInputVarN]'`, all of them column vectors.

Comment: The parameter `'LoadExternalInput'` **is** necessary. I was searching a long time for this parameter on the mathworks page until I found it here.

Answer (score 0):

`help sim` in MATLAB shows me a different command format than what you're using:

```
[t,x,y] = sim(model,timespan,options,ut);
```

I think maybe this is what you want?

```
sim('mySim', myTimeSpan, [], [myTimeVar, myInputVar]);
```

(where `myTimeSpan` is the time span to simulate over)

Comment: That's a deprecated call, and I can't specify initial state with it either.. I did look into that though, but it's not as robust as the newer syntax.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I was using an older version and didn't know about the new syntax