# MATLAB/Simulink - programmatically supply multiple external inputs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have the following Simulink model:

[image: Observer/controller Simulink model]

I would like to externally provide inputs `u[k]` and `y[k]`, i.e., I will be running simulations via MATLAB command line. I [found previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8597078/238644) that I could set the [LoadExternalInput and ExternalInput][3] options, and they default to the vector `[t u]`.

But my `u[k]` and `y[k]` are vectors, and it looks like the `ExternalInput` can only specify *one* vector. So each row of `[t u]` is the value of the entire vector `u` at time `t`.

The sizes of `u[k]` and `y[k]` in my model here are not necessarily known ahead of time. Is there a way to pass in these vectors (as structs, perhaps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Importing Data to Root-Level Input Ports](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/bsuwmmp.html) I've found that I could do something like

```
sim('myModel', 'LoadExternalInput', 'on', 'ExternalInput', 'u, y');
```

where `u` and `y` are structures with fields `time`, `signals.values`, and `signals.dimensions`; each row of `signals.values` is a vector corresponding to a n element of `time`. `signals.dimensions` is the dimension of `signals.values`. I have to manually set the In1 ports to expect the same dimension as `u.signals.values` (well, I can of course do it programatically before hand..):

> **Note**   You must set the **Port dimensions** parameter of the Inport or the Trigger block to be the same value as the `dimensions` field of the corresponding input structure. If the values differ, an error message is displayed when you try to simulate the model.

(from ["Importing Data Structures to a Root-Level Input Port"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/bsuwn_8.html))

What's the point of setting `signals.dimensions` if I have to set the dimension on the In1 block manually anyhow? Anyway that might have to be how I do this: just examine `u` and `y` before running the simulation, then setting the Inblock properties (programatically, of course) to expect vectors of that length.

I am still hoping there is a more elegant solution for this.